# Why do I keep getting an error that transaction size is not big enough when I input a bigger size than the requirement? And yes, I know about Wei

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, react

So my contract function is this:

```
function deposit(address _seller, uint256 amount) external payable returns(bytes32) {

    require(msg.value > 0.1 ether, "Value of the deposit must be more than 0.1 ether"); 

    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(msg.value, block.timestamp, _seller)); 

    Deposit storage _deposit = depositByHash[hash]; 

    _deposit.depositAmount = amount; 

    _deposit.buyer = msg.sender;
    
    _deposit.seller = _seller;  

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, _seller, amount, hash);

    return hash; 
  }
```

However, when I input the following in my UI:

```
function blockchainTalk(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  contract.deposit(
"0xF025B4AC25D5DC1FfD77B099a31ddc269D55c039",
ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
{gasLimit: 5000000});
}
```

I get this error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32603,"message":"Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Value of the deposit must be more than 0.1 ether'"
```

What the hell!? The amount I provide as input is way higher than the requirement (also in tests all seems to work).

I'm still new, so help me wrap my head around it, please <3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so apparently the problem is the fact that `msg.value == 0`. Should delete the `amount` parameter and add the amount to `msg.value` instead.

Comment: I am not getting your logic. why are you passing  `uint256 amount` parameter if you can take everything from `msg.value` , sending more money to the contract seems illogical so you should take it all by default